# when executing the go get command to install fabric-ca, I'm getting an error

Tags: go, github, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

when executing

```
go get -u github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/cmd/
```

from the [fabric-ca guide](https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users-guide.html), I get the following error:

```
# cd /home/pi/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca; git pull --ff-only


error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied
    package github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/cmd: exit status 1`
```

I tried git cloning and it downloaded everything from the fabric-ca repository, then I tried installing fabric-server and client by myself like this:

```
sudo make fabric-ca-server
```

this also produced the following error:

```
Building fabric-ca-server in bin directory ...
/bin/sh: 1: go: not found
Makefile:91: recipe for target 'bin/fabric-ca-server' failed
make: *** [bin/fabric-ca-server] Error 127
```

Comment: Have you tried running make without sudo? sudo does not preserve your environment by default, including PATH.

Comment: Peter is correct .... running make under sudo will fail

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your GOPATH is set to `/home/pi/go` and appears that you do not have access to somewhere along the path to `/home/pi/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca`.

I'd check make sure that the user you are running `go get` with has R/W access to `/home/pi/go/src`